# Android Runnable working only once

Tags: android, multithreading, animation, runnable, android-handler

I am trying to rotate my image. I wrote my function to check rotate speed in the image. In the logic everything is ok but I am using runnable and the `setrotate` method is working only once.

This is a my source:

```
public void rotateimages() {
    myHandler = new Handler();
    runnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            double k = 30;

            double speed = Math.PI / k;
            for (alpa = 0; alpa < (Math.PI * 6 + res * 2 * Math.PI / 5); alpa += speed) {
                latcirclelayout.setRotation(latcirclelayout.getRotation()
                        - ((float) alpa));

                k = Math.min(k + 0.2, 240);
                speed = Math.PI / k;
            }

        }
    };
    myHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 100);
}
```

I debugged it and the alpha value is changed everytime but the rotate is working only once.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is just a tight loop - you're executing all the iterations in one go, basically, calling `setRotation` lots of times. I strongly suspect that all the calls to `setRotation` *are* being made... but you're not seeing anything but the last one. If you want to use this code for animation, you'd need to execute your code *repeatedly* - but only calling `setRotation` once per iteration.

You could check that by adding a log entry on each iteration of the loop - I'm sure you'll see that it executes all the iterations in very quick succession.

(I suspect there may be something else built into Android to make animation simpler than that, but I don't know offhand. The [animation tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/index.html) may well help you.)

Comment: i loged alpa  and alpa  changed in for loop. complitly,i did not understand you.can you show(write) source ? @Jon Skeet

Comment: @viviano: No, not right now. What don't you understand in my answer?

Comment: i must write setrotate on on time.it means  to write outside in for loop @Jon Skeet

Comment: @viviano: As I said, you should read the animation tutorial - but if that doesn't help, you'll need a timer of some kind, where you keep the current state between invocations. I'm *sure* if you research animation on Android you'll find plenty of examples.

Comment: yes i searched it but i have very big interes what is a wrong.please rewrite my source and show me your solution.thanks

Comment: @viviano: No. I'm not even an Android developer; in order to give the best, idiomatic solution I'd have to do exactly the same research that I've suggested you should do. I've explained what's wrong with your current code, and given you pointers for what you should research to find the solution... I'm not going to just write your code for you.